# Which tools can be used to safely cut bone?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, bones

I need to cut various types of bone for its marrow (ie, leg of lamb, or pork bone). I'm wondering what type of tool would accomplish this safely. I've considered bolt cutters, saws, large cleavers, but I'm still not sure. The bone will be stripped of meat, and will mostly be round leg bones about an inch in diameter, and half a centimeter of thickness of bone at most. For example, in this photo : http://perfecthealthdiet.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/bb-3.jpg

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47225/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-bone-cleaver - yes, there are cleavers designed for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Your question is more about work/kitchen safety (how not to end up sawn or cleft given you too are made of meat and bones) than food safety (how not to make the cut bones unfit as a food ingredient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you don't want to spend a fortune on a [Commercial Butcher Shop Band Saw](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTGA2T9SWqY), your best bet is a bone saw.

[image: 1]
Image from [Philly.com](http://articles.philly.com/2013-04-05/food/38281308_1_pig-butcher-bone)

Here's one on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006F1U030).

Here's a less expensive one from [Cabela's](http://www.cabelas.com/product/Cabelas-Stainless-Steel-Butcher-Saws/714558.uts?productVariantId=1634540&srccode=cii_17588969&cpncode=39-6251872-2&WT.tsrc=CSE&WT.mc_id=GoogleProductAds&WT.z_mc_id1=50030592&rid=20).

Here's a fairly reasonably priced [Band Saw with Grinder](http://www.sportsmansguide.com/product/index/sportsman-series8482-meat-cutting-band-saw-with-grinder?a=1305552&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=WX2*0299751000000&pm2d=CSE-SPG-15-PLA&utm_medium=PLA&utm_source=Google&utm_campaign=CI&gclid=Cj0KEQiA-uWjBRChu9ie05m5ipgBEiQAuHIuK95wfRM3dTGfMAdaN_1a2mAfglkYNjjsSmgaNZpnzJYaAuMy8P8HAQ). If I was going to do a lot of butchery, I'd consider that.